# how to uncheck the checkbox using function in angular 2 typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

how to uncheck the checkbox using function in angular 2 typescript ?

> I have added image as example !

```
<div class="filter2">
              <label class="containe" 
              *ngFor="let veh of vehicleClassArr">
              {{veh}}
              <input type="checkbox" name="{{veh}}" value="{{veh}}" (change)="filterSearchResults($event, veh,'vehicleClass')">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
  </div>

<div class="reset-btn">


<button class="filter-reset-btn" (click)="resetFilters()">Reset to Default</button>

</div>
```

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPrMH.png

Answer (score 2):

To control checkbox in typescript you have to use something like this

```
var element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("IDOfCheckbox");
element.checked = true;
```

Comment: I concur with you, even though it is quite discouraged to access the html DOM directly but this method works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional field "checked" to your vehicleClass-object and bind to this via ngModel

```
<div class="filter2">
          <label class="containe" 
          *ngFor="let veh of vehicleClassArr; let ndx=index;">
          {{veh}}
          <input id="myCheck{{ndx}}" type="checkbox" name="{{veh}}" value="{{veh}}" 
           [(ngModel)]="veh.checked" (change)="filterSearchResults($event, veh,'vehicleClass')">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
</div>
```

Then adjust your method resetFilters() as follows

```
private resetFilters(): void {
   this.vehicleClassArr.forEach(element => {
      element.checked = false;
   });
}
```

Comment: if I make additional checked all data coming from api will be checked.

Comment: Is this a question or a fact? Sorry, I don't get that. Each checkbox is handled on its own except when you use your resetFilters()-method.

Comment: I did as per your code.But Its not working.why I m not getting .but when I am trying with js like document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false; it is working for one checkbox not for all checkbox bocz of id i think .can you tell how to solve that id issue .

Comment: Okay, unfortunately I can't tell you why my solution fails, as it is standard, but I now edited my post. Please have a look at the additional index out of the *ngFor-loop which then gets attached to your id-string. Now you can start a loop and then assemble each id like  document.getElementById("myCheck" + i).checked = false;

Answer (score 0):

First, you need object array which contains one string property to display and one boolean property i.e selected to check and uncheck the checkbox.

```js
resetFilters(){
 this.vehicleClassArr.every(function(item:any) {
        return item.selected == false;
      })
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (change)="selectAll();"/>
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let veh of vehicleClassArr"> 
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="veh.selected">
  {{veh.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<button class="filter-reset-btn" (click)="resetFilters()">Reset to Default</button>
```